# Magento2 - How to override this file in magento2 Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options.php

Tags: magento2

How to override this file in Magento2

```
Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option
```